# JQuery, inicializando com função

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou em um curso online de JQuery onde o professor propôs um código assim:

```
var inicia = function(){
    var valorTotalItens = $('.valor-total-item');
    var valorBase = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < valorTotalItens.length; i++) {
        var valorItemTotal = $(valorTotalItens[i]);
        var valorItem = parseFloat(valorItemTotal.text());
        valorBase = valorBase + valorItem;
    }
    $('#quantidade-itens').text(valorTotalItens.length);
    $('#valor-itens').text(valorBase);
}
$(inicia);
```

porém, eu escrevi a última linha antes que ele passasse, e escrevi de outra forma

```
inicia();
```

Queria saber qual a diferença, e o por que, de o meu código funcionou, mesmo depois de o professor falar que estava errado, e que o mesmo não deveria rodar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sem delongas, seu professor deve ter cometido um erro em falar que seu código não iria funcionar. O que você fez foi utilizar algo que é muito comum em `JavaScript` puro que é criar uma ***Expressão de função***, que é quando você atribui o endereço de uma função a uma variável.

Uma das formas (Se não for a única) de invocar essa função sem `JQuery` é justamente chamando essa variável com um "abre e fecha parênteses", e você fez exatamente isso: `inicia();` É muito comum isso.

O que o comando `$(inicia)` faz é utilizar o `JQuery` *selector* para retornar um objeto `JQuery`. Como seu *selector* é uma função, o que vai ocorrer é que a função será chamada e seu retorno será encapsulado num objeto JQuery.

Logo, a cada vez que utilizar `$(inicia)`, sua função será executada da mesma forma que `inicia();` ocorre em JS puro. A diferença é que a `$(inicia)` retorna um objeto `JQuery` e a instrução `inicia();` não.

Comment: Obrigado man :D